# Retrieving permissions from my database is always null

Tags: java, shiro

I'm having an issue where everything works such as roles, and authentication. However, my development has come to a halt because I cannot get the permissions for an account. Permissions always return null and I don't know why.

```
DefaultSecurityManager defaultSecurityManager = new DefaultSecurityManager();
ModularRealmAuthenticator authenticator = new ModularRealmAuthenticator();
authenticator.setAuthenticationStrategy(new AtLeastOneSuccessfulStrategy());
defaultSecurityManager.setAuthenticator(authenticator);
ModularRealmAuthorizer authorizer = new ModularRealmAuthorizer();
authorizer.setPermissionResolver(new WildcardPermissionResolver());
defaultSecurityManager.setAuthorizer(authorizer);
JdbcRealm realm = new JdbcRealm();
realm.setDataSource(DatabaseUtil.DATA_SOURCE);
realm.setAuthenticationQuery("SELECT password FROM account WHERE username = ?");
realm.setUserRolesQuery("SELECT accountRole FROM account WHERE username = ?");
realm.setPermissionsQuery("SELECT permissions FROM account WHERE username = ?");
realm.setPermissionsLookupEnabled(true);
realm.setCredentialsMatcher(new PasswordMatcher());
defaultSecurityManager.setRealm(realm);
SecurityUtils.setSecurityManager(defaultSecurityManager);
```

Comment: What have you tried? (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
What happens when you run your permissions query manually?